# Format Yii2 GridView column as a URL

Tags: url, gridview, yii2

I need to format the text in one column of a GridView as a URL that will navigate to the detail view of that row's record, instead of using the 'View' button in the action column; seems like something that would be a really common requirement. Below is the existing column definitions, but I want to format organization_name as a URL to the same location as the 'View' button in the action column, which is 'application/view?id=' with the value of the id column

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        'id',
        'organization_name:text:Organization',
        'address1:text:Address',
        'city',
        'state',
        'status',
        'fullName',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'visibleButtons' => ['delete' => false]
        ],
    ],
]); ?>
```

I've tried playing around with a similar question here in StackOverflow, but apparently it's not "similar" enough, because I get nowhere with it.
Any help would be VERY much appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
[
     'attribute' => 'organization_name',
     'value' => function ($model) {
          return Html::a(
              $model->organization_name,
              ['view', 'id' => $model->id],
              [
                 'title' => 'View',
              ]
          );
      },
      'format' => 'raw',
],
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code I am currently using. 
It will display empty cell in case of 'null value'. It will check for ACL and will display link if user have permission to access the view page, or it will just display organization name if user doesn't have permission.

```
...
'id',
// 'organization_name:text:Organization',
[
    'attribute' => 'organization_name',
    'label' => 'Organization',
    'format' => 'raw',
    'value' => function ($dataProvider) {
        $name = isset($dataProvider->organization_name) ? $dataProvider->organization_name : '';
        $id = isset($dataProvider->id) ? $dataProvider->id : '';
        if($name && $id){
            if(\Yii::$app->user->can('application/view')){
                $name = Html::a($name, ['application/view', 'id' => $id], ['class' => '']);
            }
            return $name;
        }
     },
],
...
```

You can remove `$app->user->can()` statement if, you have not implemented ACL.

Comment: Very interesting solution. As the application will work out, ACL will prevent unauthorized users from accessing the index page in the first place, but this is a nice snippet to keep on hand. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Below code also will work.

```
[
    'format' => 'raw',
     'value' => function ($dataProvider) {
      $organization_name = isset($dataProvider->organization_name) ? $dataProvider->organization_name : '';
     $id = isset($dataProvider->id) ? $dataProvider->id : '';
     if ($organization_name && $id) {
         if(Yii::$app->user->can('application/view')){
           $organization_name = Html::a($organization_name, ['application/view', 'id' => $id], ['class' => '','target'=>'_blank',]);
          }
           return $organization_name;
        }
     },
    'label' => 'Organization',
],
```